# SQL comparison <=all(boolean result) provides different result to >=all(boolean result)

Tags: sql

On SQLZoo, I found an answer to a question I don't understand. The question was:

"List each continent and the name of the country that comes first alphabetically."

datatable:

[image]

And the answer to this was:

```
Select  x.continent, x.name
From world x
Where x.name <= ALL (select y.name from world y where x.continent=y.continent)
ORDER BY name
```

which produces this table:
[image]

If I change the query so that the comparison operator is : "... x.name >=ALL(..",   instead of  ,"... x.name <= ALL(...", it gives me the lowest alphabetical country in each continent instead (e.g. Zimbabwe for the continent africa), I don't understand why these have different outcomes

with >= in the query: [image]

So what I don't understand and would like help on here is:

a) why is it permissible to use this comparison operator when dealing with these strings? is this because the subquery here is effectively a boolean test?

b) is the more/less than comparison itself affecting the ordering, or rather order of search, of the country table that occurs in the second query? as this would be the only way I could think this behaviour is occuring

Any help to improve my understanding of this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: It is very simple indeed. In one case you are looking for the name that is less than or equal to the one in the current row. In Europe for example, Andorra is not less than nor equal to Albania, so that row doesn't qualify. Albania on the other hand, is less than Andorra and equal to Albani so it is the expected answer. In the case of >= logic is the same, but this time you are looking for the last one alphabetically. BTW, other than sampling no one would use it to query the min or max country by continent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it helps to understand that this:

```
 Where x.name <= ALL (select y.name from world y where x.continent=y.continent)
```

is basically equivalent to:

```
where x.name = (select min(y.name) from world y where x.continent=y.continent)
```

I think this is more commonly used (there is a difference when there are no matches in the subquery).

But back to the first form.  If you remove the `=`, then this returns no rows:

```
 Where x.name < ALL (select y.name from world y where x.continent=y.continent)
```

Why?  Because no `name` is less than all the names on their continent.  This is a tautology, because the `name` itself is in the continent and it is not less than itself.

That may give a glimpse to you of what is happening and why `<=` is different from `>=`.  For `>=` you are looking for a name that is *bigger* than all names (other than itself).  That would be the maximum name rather than the minimum.

Comment: Thanks for answering Gordon, that's starting to shed light on whats happening here, but when I run it with >= I am actually getting countries that are lowest in alphabetical order for their continent (such as Zimbabwe for the continent) rather than size of name, so I feel there is still more to this

Comment: @Georgec . . . "Zimbabwe" is the HIGHEST in the alphabetical ordering for the continent, not the lowest.  It all make sense.  The comparisons are based on string comparisons, not length.

Comment: Ah sorry I misunderstood you there, that makes perfect sense of the last remaining issue and resolves this question completely. Thanks gordon